# Ionic PWA get version number from config.xml

Tags: webpack, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I want to show the version number from config.xml in an Ionic PWA.

It is easy to get it done for ios/android builds using ionic native app version plugin.

But what is a good approach for a PWA build 
(npm run build --release --prod)?

Comment: Try this [github post](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) to get the app version from config file.

Comment: I know this plugin and we use it, but it doesn't work in the PWA version.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so if cordova-plugin-app-version is not available on PWA, an alternative way to access to config.xml file is using a grunt task that copy the version to your templates (As you know, on Ionic the config.xml file is not placed on a "servable" location, so there is no way to read the version on execution time from config.xml).

For example, if we control the app version in package.json, we can config a grunt task that copy the version both to config.xml and src/index.html.

1. On **package.json** set the app version.

   ```
   {
   "name": "my-app",
   "version": "1.0.7",
   ...
   ```
2. Install **grunt** on your project.

   ```
   $> npm install grunt --save-dev
   $> npm install grunt-string-replace --save-dev
   ```
3. Set version on config.xml and index.html, and create the gruntfile.js that replace the version number each time you release a version.

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget version="1.0.7" id="...
```

**src/index.html**

```
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Ionic App</title>
      <meta name="version" content="1.0.7">
      ...
```

**gruntfile.js**

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      // replace version to config.xml
      'string-replace': {
        inline:{
          files: {
             'config.xml': 'config.xml',
          },
          options: {
            replacements: [{
              pattern: /widget version="([\d\D]*?)"/ig,
              replacement: 'widget version="' + '<%= pkg.version %>"'
            }]
          }
        }
      },
      // replace version to index.html
      'string-replace': {
        inline:{
          files: {
            'src/index.html': 'src/index.html',
          },
          options: {
            replacements: [{
              pattern: /name="version" content="([\d\D]*?)"/ig,
              replacement: 'name="version" content="' + '<%= pkg.version %>"'
            }]
          }
        }
      },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace']);

    };
```

4. Using Meta component, read version from index.html if plugins are not available.

   ```
   import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';
   import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   ...
   @IonicPage({
     name: 'main'
   })
   @Component({
     selector: 'page-main',
     templateUrl: 'main.html',
   })
   export class MainPage {
     protected versionNumber: string;
     constructor(private app: AppVersion, private meta: Meta) {
       if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
         this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(
           (v) => { this.versionNumber = v;},
           (err) => { 
             // PWA
             const viewport = this.meta.getTag('name=version');
             this.versionNumber = viewport.content;
           }
         );
       }else{
         // Debug
         const viewport = this.meta.getTag('name=version');
         this.versionNumber = viewport.content;
       }
     }
     ...
   ```
5. Print the app version number on your html template.

   ```
   <div  class="app-version" text-center>version {{ versionNumber }}</div>
   ```

Comment: For those, who do it for the first time: 

1. Read the Grunt gruntjs.com/getting-started first 
2. If everything is set up correctly, after running "grunt default" in Terminal you will see the message "2 files changed". 
3. To avoid running the "grunt default" manually, update the line "start": "grunt default && ng serve" in your main package.json. It will run grunt for you every time you do "npm start". 
IMPORTANT: check the path to the files in your code, especially in a multi-app project.

Answer (score 1):

Found proper way to do all that with using custom webpack configuration and webpack.DefinePlugin. It's working everywhere, during `ionic serve` as well (as I needed because I send that to API), and not only on real devices as cordova-plugin-app-version. Only place where it's not working is when you do `ionic serve --devapp` ([issue in @ionic/angular-toolkit](https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/108))

Everything below is for Ionic 4 (Angular 7):

- add @angular-builders/custom-webpack@7 @angular-builders/dev-server@7 dev packages with `yarn add @angular-builders/custom-webpack@7 @angular-builders/dev-server@7 --dev`
- need to replace architect.build and architect.serve builders in angular.json with new ones:

```
...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"
            },
...
```

```
...
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
...
```

- create custom.webpack.config.js with next content:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
console.log('[WEBPACK] custom.webpack.config.js is loaded');

function getAppVersion() {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

  const content = fs.readFileSync('./config.xml').toString('utf-8');
  const config = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, 'text/xml');
  return config.getElementsByTagName('widget')[0].getAttribute('version');
}


module.exports = (config, options) => {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'APP_VERSION': JSON.stringify(getAppVersion()),
    }),
  );

  return config;
};
```

- if all done correctly, you will see `[WEBPACK] custom.webpack.config.js is loaded` in terminal when running the app.
- now global variable APP_VERSION will be injected and should be available in any place of the app. `console.log('APP_VERSION', APP_VERSION);`. With that you can inject other variables like that which known only during build time or adding other custom Webpack plugins.
- you may need to add APP_VERSION definition for TypeScript into your custom-typings.d.ts as next:

```
// Variables injected by webpack DefinePlugin
declare const APP_VERSION: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [@pablo.nunez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932746/pablo-nunez) give the right solution but for me i have to make a small modification in the Gruntfile.js to successfully change both `index.html` and `config.xml` files in the same time.

**here is my modified Gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // replace version to config.xml and index.html in the same action
    'string-replace': {
      inline: {
        files: {
          'config.xml': 'config.xml',
          'src/index.html': 'src/index.html'
        },
        options: {
          replacements: [
            {
              pattern: /widget id="([\d\D]*?)" version="([\d\D]*?)"/gi,
              replacement: 'widget id=' + '"$1"' + ' version="' + '<%= pkg.version %>"'
            },
            {
              pattern: /name="version" content="([\d\D]*?)"/gi,
              replacement: 'name="version" content="' + '<%= pkg.version %>"'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace']);
};
```

I also integrate the fact that in IONIC 4 (Angular) project, the project id is automatically replaced before the version number in the `config.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way, for those who only have a PWA in ionic 4

**1. src/index.html**

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>title App</title>
  <meta name="version" content="0.0.1">
  ....
```

**2. page.ts**

```
  ...
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    const aux: any = document.getElementsByTagName('META');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
     if (aux[i].name === 'version') {
       this.versionNumber = aux[i].content;
      }
    }
  }
  ....
```

**3. page.html**

```
  ....
  <div *ngIf="versionNumber">
    <ion-text color="dark">
      <p>{{versionNumber}}</p>
    </ion-text>
  </div>
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version you can access your config.xml version, from your controller or template.

Using Ionic 4, add the Cordova plugin and Ionic Native wrapper:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version
$ npm install @ionic-native/app-version
```

And add AppVersion as a provider inside of your page main.ts

```
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
...
@IonicPage({
  name: 'main'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-main',
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
})
export class MainPage {
   protected versionNumber: string;
   constructor(private app: AppVersion) {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
         this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(
            (v) => { this.versionNumber = v;}
         );
      }else{
         this.versionNumber = '???';
      }
   }
   ...
```

Then on your .html template main.html you can print the app version number:

```
<div  class="app-version" text-center>version {{ versionNumber }}</div>
```

Also (read official doc), you can access to appName, appPackageName, appVersionCode and appVersionNumber.

Comment: But this doesn't solve it for PWA where I don't have the plugins available, right?

Comment: Yes, I proposed another solution for PWA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231990/ionic-pwa-get-version-number-from-config-xml/48372726#48372726

Comment: Great. Will try that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created an npm module that generates a `buildInfo.ts` file to your Ionic project - you can then import that file and get build number and build date. You can find the module here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-build-info.