# Ionic/Angular Dynamic component import

Tags: angular, ionic3

i have an ionic app which i want to run both on the browser and on a mobile device. am trying to add some condition to only import the native component if we are or the mobile device whatx best way to do this.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
import { AppVersion } from "@ionic-native/app-version";
@IonicPage()
@Component({ selector: "page-more", templateUrl: "more.html" })
export class MorePage {
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private appVersion: AppVersion;
  ) {
    this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(ver => {
      this.appVerStr = ver;
    });

  }
```

in the example above i want to import AppVersion only when on mobile device as this is not available to the browser i get a cordova_not_found error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cordova executes only on devices, not in browser. The way to avoid errors when viewing your build in a browser is to wrap Cordova commands in a platform if statement. In example:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { AppVersion } from "@ionic-native/app-version";

     constructor(private platform: Platform, private appVersion: AppVersion) {
        this.platform.ready().then(function () {
          if (platform.is('cordova')) {
                    this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(ver => {
              this.appVerStr = ver;
            });
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: yeah you are right but the question was how we can import the library which is not possible  .. I guess @user1108509 is concert about the memory uses

Comment: refer the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231990/ionic-pwa-get-version-number-from-config-xml

Comment: as I told you ..you are right ..we can use condition to separate the cordova realetd part bcz cordova.js is not available in browser but the read the question title ..title says that he need to import library conditionally .. its not possible but angular treeshaker will remove the import at build time :)

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't conditionally import libraries .. you can do something like import both the library, inject both in your constructor and create one function and based on the platform(`this.platform.is('browser')` or in your case `this.platform.is('android')`) you can write the code.

Don't worry about the memory uses..angular [treeshaker](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) will automatically removed unused code for you :)

**UPDATE:**

```
if (platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(ver => {
          this.appVerStr = ver;
        });
      } else {
        // code related to browser thing
      }
```